# Disable validation in update form - CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp

I have a form that i use to register and update data.
It works fine, but when i update the data, the model validation returns false, because the value inserted already exists.

I have the following code:

```
/* Validation Rule*/
public $validate = array(
    'unique' => array(
        'rule' => array('unique', 'field in the table'),
        'message' => 'The field cannot be empty.'
    )
    ...
)
/* Function that check if the value already exists */
public function unique($value, $field) {
    $check = $this->find('count', array(
        'recursive' => -1,
        'conditions' => array(
            $this->Alias.$field => $value
        )
    ));

    return $check == 0;
}
```

So, how can i disable the unique rule, but keeping the other rules?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `on` in your validation rules and accept this validation only on `create`:

```
public $validate = array(
    'unique' => array(
        'rule' => array('unique', 'field in the table'),
        'message' => 'The field cannot be empty.',
        'on' => 'create'
    );
);
```

#### Reference:

- [**Data Validation**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#on)

Answer (score 4):

You can remove validation on the fly before updating data from controller .

```
  // Completely remove all rules for a field
   $this->validator()->remove('field in the table');

 // Remove 'unique' rule from field in the table
 $this->validator()->remove('field in the table', 'unique');
```

[Removing rules from the set](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#removing-rules-from-the-set)

Comment: I'm my login function, I'm validating the username and password against the model before proceeding with authentication. In this case the "on" modifier doesn't work. Remove the validation on the fly is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

I used this in MyController of cakephp 2.8:

```
 $this->MyModel->validator()->remove('field_name');
```