# How to disable vailidation rule in controller - cakephp 2.6.7

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-2.6, cakephp-2.x

I am using CakePHP 2.6.7. I want to disable validation on csv file upload. So in my case, first answer of [Disable validation in update form - CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24020842/disable-validation-in-update-form-cakephp)
is not applicable. I try with:

```
$this->validator()->remove('email');
```

But it is not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it works for me:

```
unset($this->Customer->validate['email']);
```

In general:

```
   unset($this->Model->validate['validated field']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps, instead of removing the validation rule, the same behavior can be accomplished by setting `required=false` in the rule:

```
public $validate = array(
    'email' => array(
        'rule' => array('email', true),
        'message' => 'Please supply a valid email address.',
        'required' => false
    )
);
```

If you still want to remove the rule during runtime, unsetting the key in the `Model::validate` array may work if you call it from the controller. However, you may want to disable validation for a field in the model just after a form has been submitted and before it has been saved (for example, based on the value of another field). In this stage, the validation rules have already been loaded, and modifying the `Model::validate` array will have no effect. Instead, you have to work with the `ModelValidator` object.

> All validation rules are stored in a `ModelValidator` object, which holds every rule set for each field in your model.

Something like this should work:

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()){
    if (!empty($this->data[$this->alias]['csv_field'])) { //example
         $this->validator()->remove('email');
    }
}
```